# Primitive function problem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Let F(x) be the primitive of the function $f(x)=|\sin x|$.
Calculate $$ \lim_{x  → ∞} \frac{F(x)}{x} $$
Note that L'Hospital rule can't be applied .

Comment: The primitive is a function with infinite ramifications.That's the point where i got stuck.

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv That's a very complicated way to state the fact that if $F(x)$ is a primitive, then so is $F(x) + C$ for any constant $C$. Why don't you just _pick one_ and go with it?

Comment: The constants have to be properly picked so that F(x) is still a continous function.

Comment: Adding constant will not change the continuity of the function $F(x)$.

Comment: And, even if the choice of constant did matter somehow, the value of the limit does not depend on it.

Comment: @anubhav   im sorry the mistake i have made in my problem.I edited it

Comment: Why can't you use LHR?

Comment: because you will obtain f(x) which has no limit

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Note that
$$
\int_0^\pi |\sin t|\,dt=2,
$$
that
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x|\sin t|\,dt
$$
is one primitive of $x\mapsto |\sin x|$, that
$$
F(x+\pi)=2+F(x),
$$
that $F$ is monotonically increasing, and finally that
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{F(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{F(x)+C}{x}.
$$
Can you conclude from these hints?

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x  → ∞} \frac{F(x)}{x}= \lim_{x  → ∞} \frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x}=\infty $$

Comment: where did (x^2)/2 come from?

Comment: Assuming that primitive means essentially anti-derivative, then $\frac{1]{2}x^2$ is an anti-derivative of $|x|$ in the region where $x>0$...

Comment: I apologize , i didnt notice the mistake in my problem..